# multiple submit buttons on the same page issue

Tags: javascript

I have two submit buttons on the same page. It doesn't seem to be working when I submit the page. Here is my code.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
   <?php
    if ($_POST['Submit_1'])
    {
      echo "Submit_1"; 
    }   
    if ($_POST['Submit_2'])
    {
      echo "Submit_2";
    }
    ?>
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit_2" value="Add more"  onclick=" validateForm('form1');return false;"  >
    <input type="submit" name="Submit_1" value="Submit"  onclick=" validateForm('form1');return false;"  >
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please explain better what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Also, you forgot to close your string in `$_POST['Submit_2']`

Comment: The page doesn't seem to be posting to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return false;` will stop the buttons from submitting the form.

Comment: then the submit is happening in your javascript, and that is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Use type `button` instead of `submit`.

Answer (score 0):

**You are using JavaScript to validate the form, then return false: the submit never propagates** (unless it's part of your JavaScript we don't have).  You need to submit after validation, and add a way to distinguish the button presses via JavaScript (like another parameter to your submit), or don't use JavaScript and PHP will handle it nicely for you.

Comment: I have document.form1.submit(); after validation. How do I pass another parameter for submit?